# Communicating between an android chrome browser and an app

Tags: android, google-chrome, webintents

I need to be able to call an app and get response back on js.

I understand that those could have been achieved by the abandoned Web Intents. Any other way to achieve this?

I'm also curious about iOS, but that's a different question.

Comment: have you tried to use a webview? the api from the webview is much more open and allow you to get the html result for example.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that. But the idea is to allow third party websites to communicate with my app (using a provided js library). I would rather not control the browser environment